# pallet-mmr-rpc missing impl

Tags: rust

this is my service config.
[image]
this is my rpc config.
[image]
this is error message.
[image]

Comment: You're missing a runtime impl of pallet_mmr it seems

Comment: Please don't share screenshots, instead share code snippets with mardown syntax [here is how](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks)  where possible

Comment: @Purple_Turtle, yes! I fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the `MmrRuntimeApi` of `pallet-mmr-rpc`.

Comment: Where is this configured? https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.17/bin/node/rpc/src/lib.rs#L113  this is the only `pallet-mmr-rpc` they use.

Comment: The runtime api is implemented in the runtimes.